# Different imap mailboxes uid trouble

Tags: imap, pop3, uid

I'm working about an email manager that can manage more than one mailboxes.
This is my scenario: I get the mails by a mailbox and I store their properties in a database, uid included. The mailbox can be configured to be downloaded with imap or pop3 protocol, it depends on the mailbox itself.

**POP3 uids:**  *The unique-id of a message is an arbitrary server-determined string, consisting of one to 70 characters in the range 0x21 to 0x7E, which uniquely identifies a message within a maildrop and which persists across sessions.*

**IMAP uids:** *a 32-bit value assigned to each message, which when used with the unique identifier validity value (see below) forms a 64-bit value that MUST NOT refer to any other message in the mailbox or any subsequent mailbox with the same name forever.*

So, it is almost impossible to find two equal POP3 uids, although between different mailboxes. But is more likely to happen with IMAP uids.

So, I need the certainty that the uids are all different.
I don't need the code to do it, I need only to know if it is possible to do it, and how to do it, the need for a correct reasoning do.

Comment: Why not store the uid alongside an id that identifies the correction/server/user/etc.

Comment: The problem is that I can't change the table structure, that it is: timestamp,from,to,cc,subject,body,attachment. Otherwise it would be a good idea. @RowlandShaw

Comment: SO, concatenate an accountid to the UID.  <acct #>-<uidvalidity>-<uid>

Comment: have you seen this [What is the right way to track last email message?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69009809/5151148)

Answer (score 3):

The POP3 standard does not guarantee the UIDs to be unique -- you can see different messages with a common UID.

IMAP has no persistent UIDs which would work in the way you want them to work. The UIDs are guaranteed to be unique within a single mailbox, but under certain circumstances they might get changed (see RFC 3501 and the UIDVALIDITY response). In short, the only guarantee that IMAP provides is that a triplet of `(mailbox name, UIDVALIDITY, UID)` will ever refer to a single message, no matter what happens. This is useful for e.g. caching message parts, because they are guaranteed to be immutable. Please take care to realize that this does *not* mean that a single message will be always assigned the same triplet -- not at all, even if it remains in the same mailbox.

There are non-standard extensions which attempt to provide some kind of a GUID for you, but these differ between the IMAP server implementations and are not available everywhere.

Comment: Is it possible that two different imap account have duplicate UID?

Comment: @DS9, yes, of course! The UIDs are only unique within one "mailbox" (also known as "folder"), and only until the corresponding `UIDVALIDITY` value changes. These UIDs are not globally unique.