# What is the right way to track last email message?

Tags: email, imap

I need to write a parser for e-mail messages across some IMAP servers. It runs as a cron task and stores results in the DB.

I need a way fetch only messages that were not parsed already by previous runs.

There is an existing DB schema that suggests that the implementer should use UID to track "new" messages of a one particular mailbox. I wonder if it is correct...

What I'm seeing is that [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.1) says UID, UIDVALIDITY and mailbox name can all change in different circumstances.

More specifically UID may change between sessions and you can tell if it did if UIDVALIDITY changed.

So I can't store UID with UIDVALIDITY in the DB for a message and be certain that this pair of numbers would not be meaningless in future runs.

RFC3501 also says:

> Unique identifiers MUST be strictly ascending in the mailbox at all times.

So lets assume UIDVALIDITY changes. All UIDs are regenerated for a mailbox.

Does this mean that previous UID 1000 for the last message will be strictly higher than 1000?  Or does it just mean that older messages must have lower UIDs than newer ones and have no relation to previous UIDs?

Moreover if I were to tie to Message-ID instead of UID. I found out [RFC-2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4) says that Message-ID SHOULD exist in a message which means that there can be no Message-ID at all.

**So how do I keep track of which messages I already analyzed and which are "new" between parser runs?**

Comment: You might be reading too much into it.  UIDVALIDITY can change, but normally doesn't.  If it does, that means your should throw out your cache.

Comment: Secondly, if your goal is to process every incoming message once, it is better to insert yourself into the SMTP reception path, not IMAP.

Comment: @Max, thanks, can you hint what SMTP reception path is? RFC section?

Comment: It'll be server specific.  Most SMTP server software allows you to run scripts on reception.   Eg, this is how spamassassin works.  If you're using Gmail or the like though, you won't have this option since you don't control the server.

Comment: @Max Oh, I see. I have a lot of different email servers in DB to work with and a lot of e-mail addresses and no server I control.

Answer (score 0):

UIDVALIDITY changes when a mail box renamed or deleted.
Fortunately the mail servers such as in Gmail, Yahoo, Microsoft Exchange allow renaming or deleting only mail boxes that created by user. so in my view through this approach the UIDs in Inbox, Sent, Delete are always unique.